# FuelPHP - Use Asset it Twig template

Tags: fuelphp

I'm starting using FuelPHP.
Currently, I'm able to display a wonderful page without any images or style.  I'm happy. :P

But I would like to insert my CSS and some images.  So, I've tried to used the «Asset» function, as described in the documentation (http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/asset/config.html).
But when I insert something like «<script src="{{ Asset::js('bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>» in my template, I got this error:

```html
Twig_Error_Syntax [ Error ]:
Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("end of print statement" expected) in "index.twig" at line 223
```

What's wrong?  How can I use Asset:: ?
Thanks a lot
(And sorry if it's a noob's question :/)

Comment: **Controller**  `<?php 
class Controller_Accueil extends Controller{
 
    public function action_index(){
  $data = array();
  $data['titre'] = 'Accueil';
  return View_Twig::forge('accueil/index2.twig', $data);
    }
    }`  **Template**  `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
 <head>
  <title>{{ titre }}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ Asset::css('style.css') }}">
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Hello World</p>
 </body>
</html>`  Without the <link> tag, it works.  With the <link> tag… I've got the error.  CSS file exists and is readable.  **EDIT : sorry, I don't know how to format better :(**

Comment: There is a twig extension in the parser package which contain some fuel related functions. Also, the way you tried is PHP syntax which doesn't work in twig (just for future cases).

Answer (score 0):

Aha!  I've found how it works.
It's not `Asset::css` but `asset_css` and it generates all the `link` tag.
so `{{ asset_css('style.css')|raw }}` is perfect.